# shared_ptr и ошибка _crtisvalidheappointer(block)

Tags: c++, указатели, память, smart-pointer

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка. В конце срабатывают 2 деструктора и вылетает ошибка: _crtisvalidheappointer(block). Заранее спасибо.

```
class Call
{
public:
    int _id;
    string _name;

    Call()
    {

    }

    Call(int id, string name): _id(id), _name(name)
    {

    }

    ~Call()
    {
        printf("destructor\n");
    }

    void Print()
    {
        printf("id : %d \n", _id);
    }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector <shared_ptr<Call> > m_vCalls;

    Call emptyCall;


    shared_ptr<Call> emptyCallPtr(& emptyCall);

    m_vCalls.push_back(emptyCallPtr);
    m_vCalls[0]->Print();

    Call FirstCall(1, "First");

    shared_ptr<Call> FirstCallPtr(& FirstCall);

    m_vCalls[0] = FirstCallPtr;

    m_vCalls[0]->Print();

    m_vCalls[0]->_id = 2;
    m_vCalls[0]->Print();
    FirstCall.Print();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы передаете `shared_ptr` адрес локальной переменной, а не выделенной с помощью `new` - а потом `shared_ptr` пытается его удалить. А удалять то, что не выделено при помощи `new`, нельзя.

Попробуйте так:

```
int main()
{
   std::vector <shared_ptr<Call> > m_vCalls;

    Call * emptyCall = new Call;


    shared_ptr<Call> emptyCallPtr(emptyCall);

    m_vCalls.push_back(emptyCallPtr);
    m_vCalls[0]->Print();

    Call *FirstCall = new Call(1, "First");

    shared_ptr<Call> FirstCallPtr(FirstCall);

    m_vCalls[0] = FirstCallPtr;

    m_vCalls[0]->Print();

    m_vCalls[0]->_id = 2;
    m_vCalls[0]->Print();
    FirstCall->Print();


    return 0;
}
```